# N-Rooks Number of Solutions Backtracking

Tags: c++, algorithm, backtracking

These methods are supposed to give the count of arrangements that any number of rooks could have on a board in non-attacking arrangement.
I know I must be missing something silly here. Help me out. For some reason my returned solution count is off, even though with print statements 6 solutions are found... I've tried printing the array, printing when a solution is found... and I can't find anything that helps.

EDIT*: The User Interface is incomplete. Ignore shitty errors in it. More concerned with the incorrect results I'm getting from my findnumsolution() method. I've tried directly passing values through the constructor and it still gives me wrong answers. 3x3 board, with 3 pieces, returns 5, 4x4 with 4 returns 13.

EDIT**: Cleaned unrelated code.

```
NRooks(int board[8][8], int n, int k)
{
    numRooks = n;
    boardSize = k;
    numSolutions = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            board[i][j] = 0;
    numSolutions = findNumSolutions(board, 0, numRooks);
}

bool canPlace(int col, int row, int board[8][8])
{
    for(int i = col-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(board[i][row] == 1){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int findNumSolutions(int board[8][8], int col, int rooksLeft)
{
   if(col > boardSize||rooksLeft ==0)
       return 1;
   int nsolutions = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++){
        board[col][i] = 1;
        if(!canPlace(col, i, board)){
            continue;
        }
        nsolutions += findNumSolutions(board, col + 1, rooksLeft - 1);
        board[col][i] = 0;
    }
    return nsolutions;
}
```

Comment: Is `numSolutions` a global variable or a member of ´NRooks`? Make it local, because each invocation of `findNumSolutions` requires its own copy.

Comment: That is one thing that I missed. Still "0" though. Yeah, I know what I'm supposed to be getting I'm just wondering why this isn't working

Comment: Just change the modification of the member variable. `numSolutions = 0;`, in `NRooks::findNumSolutions` to a declaration of a local variable: `int numSolutions = 0;`. (And delete the member variable of the same name; you don't need it.) It should work now.

Comment: Actually, it did change things but the result is still off for some reason. 3x3 board with 3 pieces, I get 5 solutions, and 4x4 with 4 pieces i get 13.

Comment: I don't know. I've used the original code you posted, reoved the class and added some stuff that you don't show to make it work and it gave me good results. Do you start with a board that's all zeroes? Perhaps you should share the whole program; there may be other errors.

Comment: Should I just post it on here?

Comment: You can edit your post and replace the current code with the full program. If the program is long and has parts that are not needed, strip them first and make sure that you can reproduce the error. The important parts are the `NRooks` class and the code that uses it.

Comment: @MOehm I've tried creating the board within NRooks class, with no difference in results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error, now fixed, is that you use a member variable in a recursive function where you should use a local variable. There are two variants here: Either return the number from each call or have a global or member function and accumulate the solutions there. Don't mix these approaches.

The second error, which wasn't there in the original post, but which was introduced when you posted the whole code, is here:

```
// try placing piece in row of col
for(int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++){
    board[col][i] = 1;
    if(!canPlace(col, i, board)){
        continue;
    }
    nsolutions += findNumSolutions(board, col + 1, rooksLeft - 1);
    board[col][i] = 0;
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
// try placing piece in row of col
for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++){
    board[col][i] = 1;
    if (canPlace(col, i, board)) {
        nsolutions += findNumSolutions(board, col + 1, rooksLeft - 1);
        board[col][i] = 0;
    }
 }
```

The setting and restoring of the rook must be symmetric; that is each time a rook is placed you must rest it before trying to place a new rook or before recursing back up again. You can see that the rook is placed in every case, but is only cleaned up when it can be placed. This results in more rooks being on the board than should be.

Your check doesn't consider the the current columns, so you can either place both rook placements outside the braces or both inside. I suggest:

```
for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++){
    if (canPlace(col, i, board)) {
        board[col][i] = 1;
        nsolutions += findNumSolutions(board, col + 1, rooksLeft - 1);
        board[col][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

As an addendum, I think that the class should manage its own board. This will do away with many confusing `board` parameters. If you allocate the board size on the heap, you don't need the `MAXSIZE`, either. But beware: When board sizes get big, the counts of arrangements will overflow an `int`.

```
#include <iostream>

class NRooks {
public:
    NRooks(int n, int k);
    ~NRooks();

    int getSolutionTotal();

private:
    bool canPlace(int col, int row);
    int findNumSolutions(int col, int rooksLeft);

    int numSolutions;
    int numRooks;
    int boardSize;
    int *data;
    int **board;
};

NRooks::NRooks(int n, int k)
{
    numRooks = n;
    boardSize = k;
    numSolutions = 0;

    data = new int[k*k];
    board = new int*[k];

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) board[i] = data + k*i;
    for (int i = 0; i < k*k; i++) data[i] = 0;

    numSolutions = findNumSolutions(0, numRooks);
}

NRooks::~NRooks()
{
    delete[] data;
    delete[] board;
}

int NRooks::getSolutionTotal(){
    return numSolutions;
}

bool NRooks::canPlace(int col, int row)
{
    for (int i = col; i-- > 0; ) {
        if (board[i][row]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int NRooks::findNumSolutions(int col, int rooksLeft)
{
    if (rooksLeft == 0) return 1;
    if (col > boardSize) return (rooksLeft == 0);

    int nsolutions = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
        if (canPlace(col, i)) {
            board[col][i] = 1;
            nsolutions += findNumSolutions(col + 1, rooksLeft - 1);
            board[col][i] = 0;
        }
    }

    if (rooksLeft < boardSize - col) {
        nsolutions += findNumSolutions(col + 1, rooksLeft);
    }

    return nsolutions;
}

int main()
{
    for (int boardSize = 2; boardSize <= 6; boardSize++) {
        for (int numPieces = 1; numPieces <= boardSize; numPieces++) {
            NRooks r = NRooks(numPieces, boardSize);

            std::cout << boardSize << " board, "
                      << numPieces << " rooks, "
                      << r.getSolutionTotal() << " solutions" 
                      << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This very helpful.

Comment: I think its giving the wrong answer e.g. 3 board, 1 rooks, 3 solutions but the answer should be 9.It can be anywhere.

Comment: @user1438832: Yes, that's right. I initially made a comment that proposed an analytic approach like square1001's, but the OP said he knew what the solution should be, so I presented a fix for the OP's obvious problems. I haven't checked all solutions and I've already spent too much time with this answer.

Comment: The problem is, of course, that the code was designed for placing N rooks on an NxN board. The recursive function misses an option to skip a column and not place a rook if the number of rooks left is smaller than the number of columns left to porocess. I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader, yadda, yadda,,...

Answer (score 2):

I don't teach the bug of this code, but I have more efficient solution without backtracking. It's only a mathematics problem. 

This problem is: Given integers N and K, find the number of ways that put N rooks in the K * K board.

If N > K, the answer is zero.
If N = K, the answer is K!. Because you can select one rook in each column, so the number of ways is equal to the number of permutation of `p={1, 2, 3,..., K}`

Let's think about N < K cases.
Actually, the answer is `P(K, N) * C(K, N)`.
If the board size is N * K, you can only select the permutation that satisfies 1<=p[i]<=K and p[i]'s are different.
So there are `P(K, N)` ways.
You also choose N rows in K rows that puts the rook. And there are `C(K, N)` ways. 
Then, the final answer is `P(K, N) * C(K, N)`

If you don't know the P(Permutation) or C(Combination), please read [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html).

Finally, the answer is `P(K, N) * C(K, N)` if N <= K, otherwise the answer is zero.
The time complexity is `O(K)` and it is better than `O(P(K, N) * C(K, N))` brute-force algorithm.

Comment: Great solution.

Comment: This is a great, fast way to solve it. But I was specifically attempting to solve via backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the approach described by square1001

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long fact(int n)
{
    long long factorial=1;
    if(n<=0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    {
        factorial *= i;              // factorial = factorial*i;
    }
    return factorial;
}
long long permutation(int n, int r) {
    if( n<=0 || r<= 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return fact(n)/fact(n-r);
}

long long combination(int n, int r) {
    if(r > n / 2) r = n - r; // because C(n, r) == C(n, n - r)
    long long ans = 1;
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
        ans *= n - r + i;
        ans /= i;
    }

    return ans;
}

long long findNumSolutions(int boardSize,int numberofRooks)
{
    if(numberofRooks>boardSize || numberofRooks <=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    long long comb=combination(boardSize,numberofRooks);
    long long  perm=permutation(boardSize,numberofRooks);
    cout<<"comb : "<<comb<<endl;
    cout<<"perm : "<<perm<<endl;
    return comb*perm;
}

int main ()
{
  std::cout <<findNumSolutions(3,3)<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```